# Product ID tracking in a sorter machine (PLC programming)

Tags: plc

I'm writing a PLC program (Q Series Mitsubishi PLC, GXWORKS 2 Software) for a package sorting machine. The logic of the machine is the following:

1.Packages are induced in the conveyor. A barcode reader scanner gets the package barcode.

2.Barcode is send to our SMS (sorting management system), it calcules the exit and send it back to the PLC.

3.Package travels to the calculed exit, then is derived into the chute.

The tracking of the products is done by an encoder and a shift register. This means that every memory address represents a physical position in the conveyor. Then, the shift register move the bits representing the packages along the memory buffer, till the bit arrives to an address that represents an exit, so the package can be derived.

My problem is not the tracking of the product, but the product ID tracking:

When a package enters in the conveyor, an ID is set for that product (1,2,...,n). The idea is that this ID is used to track the state of that package, for example if the package was derived in the correct exit, if it has a damaged barcode, etc.

My question is, how can I track this ID along in an efficient way. I was thinking in use the same shift register not moving a sole bit, but moving a larger number for example |1|0000011|, where the first bit acts like a flag that represents the existence of a product and the rest of the numbers is the product ID. When the flag gets to the exit address I can substract 10000011 - 10000000 = 00000011, to get the product ID.

Is any more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Do you have a barcode scanner before the calculated exit?It makes sense to check the barcode just before the exit in order to make sure it's in the correcto location.

Comment: I only have one barcode scanner at the entrance of the machine :(

Comment: How many packages do you have at the same time on the conveyor?Do you always have  1 package at a given time on the conveyor?

Comment: There can be a maximum of 70 packages along the conveyor. Not always is going to be a  package at the entrance of the conveyor, because the induction is manual and there can be times when no packages are induced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part with the encoder is not clear to me, so I replace it with a nr x of sensors.
Maybe you can explain it better, then I will update the answer.

Now, let's imagine a simple model of the conveyor:

```
        S           S               S
        |           |               |EXIT
---------------------------------------------------
    x           x   x           x
---------------------------------------------------
```

- x are the packages on the conveyor
- s are the sensors along the conveyor
- EXIT is where the package exits

You can create a Function Block that represents a Package: FB_Package

FB_Package has following data structure :

```
TYPE ST_Package :
STRUCT
    sBarcode : STRING;
    eLocation : E_ConveyorLocation;
    eState : E_PackageState;
    uiPackageID: UINT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

Then you can create an FB_Conveyor that has/or manages an array of FB_Packages

FB_Package has a step chain which checks the current location on the conveyor.
Every time it receives a new location from the conveyor it checks in its step chain if that location is plausible considering the current location (time frame to get to the next location and if the received location is after the current location for example).
If the check is successful the package updates it's location and when the last location is reached the fbPackage instance changes it's state to ePackageExited for example.

The fbConveyor instance recognizes that the package has exited the conveyor and resets its instance in the array.

As you can see, I used ENUMS for the package location and the state because they are human readable and make your code easier to understand than shifting around with bits in bytes.